# Removing elements from singly-linked list (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a singly-linked list of integers l and an integer k, how can I remove all elements from list l that have a value of k? Preferably in O(n) time. Here's what I have:

```
// Definition for singly-linked list:
// template<typename T>
// struct ListNode {
//   ListNode(const T &v) : value(v), next(nullptr) {}
//   T value;
//   ListNode *next;
// };
//
ListNode<int> * removeKFromList(ListNode<int> * l, int k) {
ListNode iterator = l;
while(iterator != NULL)
  {
    if(iterator->value == k)
    {

    }
    iterator = iterator->next;
  }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: what problem are you facing? The code you posted is a stub: have you tried to implement the actual delete mechanics?

Comment: Probably be easier if you put `iterator = iterator->next;` in an `else`. You do not want this running if you just removed the node at `iterator` in the `if`.

Comment: Tip #1: use `std::list` or `std::forward_list`. Tip #2: lookup the remove/erase idiom.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
ListNode1<int> * removeKFromList(ListNode1<int> * l, int k) {
          ListNode1<int> *tmp = l,*prev=NULL;
          if (l==NULL) return l;
          while (tmp) {
              if (tmp->value == k)
              {
                  if (prev)
                      prev->next=tmp->next;
                  else
                      l=l->next;
                  //delete tmp; ??
              }
              else
                  prev=tmp;

              tmp=tmp->next;
          }
          return l;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeKFromList(l, k):
    if(l is None):
        return l
    curr = l
    final = ListNode(0)
    i = 1
    newhead = l
    while(curr):
        if(curr.value != k and i):
            i = 0
            newhead = curr
        if(curr.value == k):
            final.next = curr.next
            tmp = final.next
            if(tmp is None and i):
                return None
        else:
            final = curr
        curr = curr.next
    return newhead
```

Comment: Please, provide some context to your answer. It will help others who visit the site to understand the code easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution to the problem and the explanation of each step

```
# Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
# class ListNode(object):
#   def __init__(self, x):
#     self.value = x
#     self.next = None
#
def solution(l, k):
    
    """ 
    - First, check if the is empty or not, so return the empty list itself
    """
    if l is None:
        return l

    """
    - Then trying to remove the occurrences of element k in the head of the 
    linked list ( It may appear several consecutive k elements at the 
    beginning of the linked list. Even the whole linked list may compose of
    nodes with k values all )
    """
    while l.value == k and l != None:
        l = l.next
        if l == None:
            break
    """
    - Then I am checking again if the list is empty after the previous cleaning
    operation in the while loop, because it may remove all of the nodes from 
    the list ( this is a special case when the whole linked list may compose of 
    nodes with k values all)
    """
    if l is None:
        return l

    """
    - Then I am finally checking all of the remaining nodes in the list 
    and removing the connection of the nodes where the value is equal to k.
    """
    curr = l
    while curr.next:
        if int(curr.next.value == k):
            curr.next = curr.next.next
        else:
            curr = curr.next
        
    return l
```